# Rename column names with gsub and sub

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have been reading about renaming column names using gsub and sub. I want to take various column names 20220427_209944540823_SC835404_12.RCC and truncate to SC835404_12. What am I missing in my code. Currently, I am getting 209944540823_SC835404_12

```
colnames(expr_counts) <- gsub(c(".RCC"), "", sub("^[^_]*_", "", colnames(expr_counts)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
colnames(expr_counts) <- sub(".*_(.*_\\d+)\\.RCC$", "\\1", colnames(expr_counts))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5Eru5E/1).

*Details*:

- `.*` - any zero or more chars as many as possible
- `_` - an underscore
- `(.*_\d+)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars as many as possible, `_`, one or more digits
- `\.RCC` - an `.RCC` string
- `$` - end of string.

The replacement is the `\1` backreference that replaces the whole match with the Group 1 value.